# Google contact API in .NET

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am beginner in Google API for Google Contacts. I have implemented listing all contacts and adding new contact. I have now a problem with updating\editing and deleting a contact. I have tried many web examples without success. Can you help me?

```
 public static void EditContact(string id, string name, StructuredPostalAddress address)
 {
    ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));

    ContactsFeed feed = GContactService.Query(query);

    foreach (ContactEntry entry in feed.Entries)
    {
        foreach (EMail email in entry.Emails)
        {
            if (email.Address == id)
            {
                Organization org = new Organization();
                org.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork;
                org.Title = "President, CEO";
                org.Name = "John Doe Enterprises";
                org.Primary = true;
                entry.Name = new Name() { FullName = name };
                entry.PostalAddresses.Add(address);
                entry.Organizations.Add(org);
                // error:
                // Execution of request failed
                ContactEntry updatedEntry = (ContactEntry)entry.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException' occurred in
>   Google.GData.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: Execution of request failed:

Comment: Well yes, you're trying to use the `entry` variable, but there's no such variable. What did you *expect* this to do? What entry are you trying to update? Are you saving the entry in a list somewhere or something?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?